# What does #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION do in stb_image

Tags: c++, textures, stb-image

I am trying to use [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) to load image files as textures in an OpenGL program, the documentation of the header file stb_image.h states the following:

"*Do this:*

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
```

*before you include this file in *one* C or C++ file to create the implementation."*

What does this type of preprocessor directive actually do?

For the benefit of the reader, here is how my project is structured.

1. main.cpp
2. stb_image.h

The header of the main.cpp file looks likes this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include "shader.h"

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
```

Comment: Why not look at the file `stb_image.h` itself to see what it does when the macros is defined?

Comment: This is a 'common' pattern in 'header only libraries', to follow the one definition rule stuff needs to be appear in at most one .cpp file, therefore the library asks you to put #define WTV before including the file in at most one cpp this will enable the implemention in that file, all the other places will only have the declaration. [tinyobjloader](https://github.com/tinyobjloader/tinyobjloader) works like this too.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did but I couldn't really understand much what was going on, I am new to using 3rd party libraries so I didn't know what to look for, but I think Borgleader's answer sums it up well. Thank you both.

Comment: @A.Khaled if you open the [std_image.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) and go down to line 514. you can see ``#ifdef STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION`` this mean that if the macro ``STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION`` is defined the following lines will execute. This allow openGL to enable some things but this would need to look more specifically at openGL code

Comment: Question has been answered, but voting this one as duplicate anyway: [Preventing multiple #define when including headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64058036/preventing-multiple-define-when-including-headers)